# Filter out keys I need and create a new array

Tags: arrays, json, select, key, jq

```json
{
"Key": "value"
"Results": [
  {
    "KeyIwant":"value"
    ...
  }
]
}
```

I want to get a list of objects that have only the keys and their values that i specifiy.

So far Ive found something from the internet, but it creates objects and not a list and there are no commas.

```sh
jq '.Results | .[] |  with_entries(select([.key] | inside(["key","key2", "key3"])))' input.json
```

Comment: Can you show a minimal _valid_ JSON input and an exact expected output for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For efficiency, you could use `IN`:

```
[.Results[]|with_entries(select(.key|IN("KeyIwant","etc"))) ]
```

If you want the whitelist to be presented as a JSON array, say $w, then write `IN($w[])`

Comment: I think it's worth highlighting that it's the array constructor around the whole query that solve the problem "I want to get a list of objects... but it creates objects and not a list and there are no commas". That seems to be the core of the question.